# MySQL InnoDB logfiles resized - review mysql-err.log for potential problems

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery

I restarted mysqld this morning, to increase the size of the innodb logs and increase the amount of memory allocated to the innodb buffer pool.  (MySQL 5.1.53-Community on Ubuntu)

To increase the size of the innodb logs, I modified the my.cnf file, stopped mysqld, renamed the existing innodb log files, and then started mysqld again.

```
     root@mysql01:# /etc/init.d/mysql.server stop
     Shutting down MySQL
     ............ *
     root@mysql01:# ls -al ib_logfile*
     -rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  251658240 2013-02-08 08:21 ib_logfile0
     -rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  251658240 2013-02-08 08:21 ib_logfile1
     root@mysql01:# mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.OLD
     root@mysql01:# mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.OLD
     root@mysql01:# /etc/init.d/mysql.server start
     Starting MySQL
     ................................ *
     root@mysql01:#
```

The mysql01-err.log shows

```
130208  8:21:27 [Note] /opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130208  8:21:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130208  8:21:30  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130208  8:21:39  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 661 1658279774
130208  8:21:39 [Note] /opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130208 08:21:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/mysql_data/mysql01.pid ended
130208 08:22:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/mysql_data
130208  8:22:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130208  8:22:18  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 1536 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500
130208  8:22:29  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 1536 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130208  8:22:37  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 886154568, file name ./mysql-bin.001636
130208  8:22:48  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 661 1658279948
130208  8:22:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130208  8:22:48 [Note] /opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.53-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I'm concerned with the line, after the new innodb log files are written, that says

```
130208  8:22:37  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
```

---

My questions are:

Is that line expected in the log file, is this the behavior I should expect? Does this indicate a problem, or is this a normal result from creating new log files?

Is there anything in the tail of the mysql01-err.log that indicates that there was a real problem?

Was the InnoDB "crash recovery" successful? Or is there a chance that something is screwed up?

Are there any additional steps that I can take to verify that everything is fine with InnoDB, and that the steps I performed did not cause any corruption?

(I'd rather know about any problems now. It would be much better to do any additional steps to get a full recovery, sooner, rather than later.)

Answer (score 1):

It is sort of yes and no. Why would I say both?

There are still some transactional data embedded in the old ib_logfiles in conjunction with the ibdata1 file. (See [**pictorial representation**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing))

What you should have done is this:

```
mysql -u... -p... -ANe"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0"
/etc/init.d/mysql.server stop
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.OLD
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.OLD
/etc/init.d/mysql.server start
```

If you did not know of disabling [**innodb_fast_shutdown**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown), ther you steps should have been

```
/etc/init.d/mysql.server stop
/etc/init.d/mysql.server start
/etc/init.d/mysql.server stop
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.OLD
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.OLD
/etc/init.d/mysql.server start
```

Doing either of these coordinate the purging of all uncommitted writes to tables and indexes. Just looking at the error log, I think you dodged a bullet in this instance. In future, please follow this protocol.

If you are not sure either way, you could put back the old log files, set the old size of [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size), restart mysql. Then, start the process over again as I prescribed above.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The MySQL 5.1 documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html) specifies that `innodb_fast_shutdown`  should be changed from a value of `2` to a value of `1` before this procedure (before the shutdown). And that makes sense. In my case, the value was already set to 1, so I followed the procedure.  The MySQL 5.1 documentation makes no mention that a value of `0` would be preferred over a value of `1`. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I prefer zero(0). It is the slowest, but it will completely purge all needed data from the logs.